# How to set consumer.id for new Kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

According to the [docs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#oldconsumerconfigs), *Old* Consumer Configs included a `consumer.id` set to null by default:

> **consumer.id**
>   Default: null
>  
>   Description: Generated automatically if not set.

Is it possible to set the `consumer.id` for the *New* Kafka Consumer and if so, how can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you are talking about the consumer group id?

Comment: @RamanMishra There is a `consumer.id` as well.

Comment: What do you use this for? Maybe it can be replaced by `client.id` ?

Comment: @Thilo When running `kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group group_name --describe` I want to get a more meaningful `consumer.id` instead of letting Kafka generating a long and random id. `client.id` will change the first part of  `consumer.id` but it won't completely replace it. For instance if I set `client.id` to `abc` the `consumer.id` will become something like `abc-12kdl12-....`.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka automatically generates a `consumer.id` which is used by itself to identify the active consumers in a consumer group and it is **not** possible to manually set the `consumer.id` for Kafka Consumers.